# Права доступа в Apache2 на правку содержимого DocumentsRoot

Tags: права, apache2, веб-сервер, linux

Запара вот в чем. У меня openSUSE 12.2, установил Apache2. Демон апача работает под юзером wwwrun в группе www. Внимание, вопрос: как безболезненно и максимально комфортно редактировать содержимое DocumentsRoot виртуального хоста из текущего пользователя (из группы users)?

Comment: Я пока сам нашел выход только запустить демон апача от имени текущего юзера. Но мне жутко интересно чем это грозит если применить такой подход на публичном сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Поставить +w на other.
2. Добавить текущего пользователя в группу www.

Comment: А что именно значит +w?

Comment: Право записи всем остальным! А вообще man chmod.